# Generate list of random number with the sum divisible by n

Tags: python, numpy, random, generator

My concern was what is a good way to generate a list of 10 - 15 numbers that the sum of them always divisible by n.

The output should be

-8378302799

Here what I got so far, but it not a working script yet.

```
import random
import numpy as np

def get_num(x, y, n):
    return [random.choice(range(x, y, n)) if x % n != 0 else random.choice(range(x - (x % n) + n, y, n)) for x in x]


def get_list():
    numb = get_num(0, 9, 2)
    return ''.join(np.random.multinomial(numb, [1/10], size=1))

while True:
    amount = int(input("How many Do you want to generate?" + "\n"))
    for i in range(1,amount):
        get_list()
```

@Samer Ayoub, answer was what I needed, just added the sep='' so it came as I expected.

```
import random

n, m, k= 3, 9, 14
lis = [random.choice(range(0, m)) for i in range(k)]
tot = sum(lis)
print(*lis, sep = '')

while tot%n != 0:
    tot -= lis.pop()
    last = random.choice(range(0, m))
    lis.append(last)
    tot += last
```

Comment: Pick a random number, `k`, multiply it by `n` to get `total=k*n`. `total` is clearly divisible by `n`. then pick another random number, `a`, where `a < total`. final output is `a` and `total-a`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such an array? You mean adding all of the elements should be divisible by a given number, or adding any number of elements should be divisible by a given number? Can I use a single number multiple times?

Comment: @Gasper Yes sir, I added the output to question, thank you.

Comment: The output sum up is divisible by a given number

Comment: And the distribution of the individual numbers?

Comment: @Daniel There is nothing special for individual number. All the script suppose to do is generate the input amount of number list like the output:

--8378302799

--9286786482

--9132143568

Comment: Until you describe what the distribution should be, the problem is under-specified. It is extremely easy to e.g. generate 14 numbers at random and then pick the 15th number so that the sum is a given multiple. There are infinitely many choices for the 15th number, so you can pick that randomly as well. But -- if you do so the 15th number will come from a different probability distribution than the other 14. If you want to pick the vector of numbers so that it is uniformly chosen from the set of those that satisfy the constraints, some mathematical analysis is required.

Comment: The number can be truly random, it does not really matter, as there is no specific pattern here. All can be scramble up as long as the sum of all can be divide by a given number.

Comment: @JohnColeman the last number won't come from a different distribution really.  It'll just have a 1/n chance to come from one of n uniform distributions - which sums to the original uniform.  Assuming he wants uniform.

Comment: @DanielF a different uniform distribution is still a different distribution. The problem is a modular version of the problem of finding a random vector of numbers with a given sum. Since this latter problem is harder than it first appears (if you want to pick a solution uniformly from the solution space), the original problem is likely to be at least as hard. The modulus is a complicating rather than a simplifying factor. For one thing, modulo bias might be an issue with the naive solution I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement on @SamerAyoub using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

n, m, k= 3, 9, 15
arr = np.empty(k, dtype = int)
arr[1:] = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, m), k-1)
rem = arr[1:].sum() % n
arr[0]  = np.random.choice(np.arange(n - rem, m, n))

print(''.join([str(i) for i in arr]))
print(arr.sum()%n == 0)

374564205252063
True
```

There's also the (not guaranteed to be especially fast, especially if `n` is large) brute force method, which at least guarantees no bias (but doesn't guarantee ever finishing):

```
def slow_way(n, m, k):
    arr = np.empty(k)
    while arr.sum() % n != 0:
        arr = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, m), k)
    return arr
```

Comment: This is great method too, just what I wanted to use at the first place!

Comment: Is there a way you can add first number is not 0 please?

Comment: I just reversed the array. I actually messed up initially and made it so that the *last* value can't be `0`.  So I just put it first.

Comment: This is definitely a natural approach, and probably adequate for most use-cases (so +1), but it does give a (probably slight) bias, as my somewhat silly answer shows below (using a slightly different way of picking the final number).

Comment: @DanielF Bias doesn't have to be large to exist. If the last number is selected via a different process that the other ones, then you won't have solutions which are uniformly chosen from the set of all possible solutions. If you use parameters like `n, m, k= 2,5,3` then you should be able to detect an anomaly. In your case, you picked an `n` which divided your `m`, hence avoided modulo bias. It is a somewhat pedantic point, and irrelevant for OP (hence I upvoted your solution) -- but the mathematical fact remains that your algorithm does not sample solutions uniformly.

Comment: @JohnColemen I see.  Well, there's going to be bias in the first term anyway since the OP doesn't want zero.  Might as well keep all the bias bundled up together then.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit pedantic, but if anyone reading this in the future has a use-case in which questions of probability distribution matters, they should be aware that the algorithm of picking all but the last number at random and then picking the last number so as to satisfy the constraints, introduces a bias in the last number. As proof of concept:

```
import random, math

def f(k,a,b):
    """generates k random integers in a,b which sum to an even number"""
    start = [random.randint(a,b) for _ in range(k-1)]
    if sum(start) % 2 == 0:
        #pick an even number
        start.append(2*random.randint(math.ceil(a/2),math.floor(b/2)))
    else:
        #pick an off number
        start.append(1 + 2*random.randint(math.ceil((a-1)/2),math.floor((b-1)/2)))
    return start
```

For example, a typical run of `f(3,1,5)` produced `[1, 5, 2]`.

But:

```
trials = [f(3,1,5) for _ in range(10000)]
print(sum(trial[0]%2 == 0 for trial in trials)/10000) #percentage of first nums which are even
print(sum(trial[2]%2 == 0 for trial in trials)/10000) #percentage of last nums which are even
```

typical output:

```
0.3996
0.5198
```

Which shows a clear bias.

Comment: Except . . . the bias in your example is on the first number.  Which is seleted normally.

Comment: @DanielF I don't understand your comment. "unbiased" in the context of {1,2,3,4,5} means that each of those numbers have an equal probability of being selected. 40% of the integers in that set are even, hence you would expect such a number to be even 40% of the time. Thus the observed frequency of 39.96% evens in the first number is exactly the sort of thing you would expect. The fact that over 50% of the the times the last number is even means that the last number is *not* selected in an unbiased way from {1,2,3,4,5} but is instead biased in favor of {2,4}.

Answer (score 1):

Generate your list fully, check if the sum is divisible by n, if not replace last element untill it works:

```
import random

n, m, k= 3, 9, 15
lis = [random.choice(range(0, m)) for i in range(k)]
tot = sum(lis)

while tot%n != 0:
    tot -= lis.pop()
    last = random.choice(range(0, m))
    lis.append(last)
    tot += last
```

Comment: Why do hit-and-miss with the last choice? You know what its remainder mod `n` would need to be -- so you can use that to make a single choice.